# Derivative of $\sec^2(x)$

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

I know that the derivative of $\sec(x)$ is $\sec(x)\tan(x)$, so what is the derivative of $sec^2(x)$?

I want to know what derivative rules you use to derive it.

Comment: You say you already know the derivative of $\sec(x)$.  Now use the chain rule which says that $\frac{d}{dx}[(f(x))^2] = 2f(x)\cdot f'(x)$

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. I just learned chain rule, and sometimes I forget when to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember $\sec^2 x=1/\cos^2 x$.

You can use the chain rule to take the derivative:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(\cos x)^{-2}=-2(\cos x)^{-3}(-\sin x)=2\tan x\sec^2 x.
$$

Comment: At first, this answer confused me because you used cos(x)^-2, but then I remembered that sec(x)=1/cos(x) and this answer made everything make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sec^2(x)$$
Apply chain rule, setting $u= \sec(x)$
$$=\frac{du^2}{du}\frac{du}{dx}$$
$$=2u\frac{d}{dx}\sec(x)$$
$$=2\sec(x)\sec(x)\tan(x)$$
$$=2\sec^2(x)\tan(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in standard notation $\sec^2 x$ means $\Big(\sec x\Big)^2$ rather than $\sec(\sec x)$.  Therefore
$$
\frac d {dx} \sec^2 x = \frac d {dx} \Big((\sec x)^2\Big) = 2\sec x \cdot \frac d {dx} \sec x= \cdots.
$$